# how to log badrequest in web api 2?

Tags: exception, asp.net-web-api

Is there a way to catch and log badrequest or unauthorized  response code from an action in web api 2?
I tried adding onactionexecuted attributefilter and ExceptionLogger but neither of them worked.

```
public IHttpActionResult ConfirmUpload(string val)
{
   if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(val))
      return BadRequest(val);
}

public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    config.Filters.Add(new ErrorLogAttribute());
    config.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new ErrorLogger());
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

To log bad requests you can write your own LogAttribute derived from ExceptionFilterAttribute

```
public class LogAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        Log.Error(context.Exception);

        context.Response = context.Request.CreateResponse(
                HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
                new { message = context.Exception.InnerException != null ? context.Exception.InnerException.Message : context.Exception.Message });

        base.OnException(context);
    }
}
```

HttpActionExecutedContext contains information about request so you can check request status, if you need. Attribute can be applied to controller, action

```
public class ValueController : ApiController
{
    [Log]
    public IEnumerable<object> Get()
    {
    }
}
```

or added globally

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Filters.Add(new LogAttribute());
    }
}
```

also all exceptions could be catched in global.asax

```
protected void Application_Error()
{
    var ex = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();

    // ignore 404
    if (!(ex is HttpException && ((HttpException)ex).GetHttpCode() == 404))
    {
        Log.Fatal("Unhandled error catched in Global.asax", ex);
    }

    Server.ClearError();
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. I have already tried those things before. What I am guessing is return BadRequest(val); is not an exception for web api so it doesn't catch it. I will try something with actionfilters.

Comment: There is alse OnResultExecuted method that could be helpful for you

Comment: Is that method defined for web api or only for mvc?

Comment: sorry for misleading OnResultExecuted not defined for web api